# Why is my date criteria filtering incorrectly in a MsysObjects query using DCount?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access database with ~500 tables, and with a total of ~16,000 total rows across all tables. I would like to count the number of rows whose "datecreated" field is before January 1, 2019.

I am attempting to do this by querying the MsysObjects and doing a DCount for each table with a criteria that filters by date.

Let's say I were doing this on a dataset with content like this:

- table1: 10 total rows, 5 before January 1, 2019
- table2: 10 total rows, 9 before January 1, 2019
- table3: 10 total rows, 0 before January 1, 2019

### Datecreated field

I've spot-checked some of the 500 tables. The "datecreated" field is datatype: Date/Time. Format is yyyymmdd.

I have created a search where I can get a count of all rows by table, and I can filter that search by various fields. When I try to filter by the datecreated field, though, I get weird results. It doesn't filter the way I expect.

### 1. Baseline Query (without criteria):

(works great!)

```
SELECT MsysObjects.Name, DCount("*",[Name]) AS RecordTotal
FROM MsysObjects
WHERE (((Left$([Name],1))<>"~") AND ((Left$([Name],4))<>"Msys") AND ((MsysObjects.Type)=1))
ORDER BY MsysObjects.Name;
```

### Result:

(Result is as expected)

Name    RecordTotal

table1  10

table2  10

table3  10

### 2. Query with criteria added to DCount (datecreated < 01/01/2019):

```
SELECT MsysObjects.Name, DCount("*",[Name],"[datecreated]<" & #01/01/2019#) AS RecordTotal
FROM MsysObjects
WHERE (((Left$([Name],1))<>"~") AND ((Left$([Name],4))<>"Msys") AND ((MsysObjects.Type)=1))
ORDER BY MsysObjects.Name;
```

### Expected result:

Name    RecordTotal

table1  5

table2  9

table3  0

### Actual result:

Name    RecordTotal

table1  0

table2  0

table3  0

### 3. Query with differently-formatted criteria added to DCount (datecreated < 20190101):

```
SELECT MsysObjects.Name, DCount("*",[Name],"[datecreated]<" & #20190101#) AS RecordTotal
FROM MsysObjects
WHERE (((Left$([Name],1))<>"~") AND ((Left$([Name],4))<>"Msys") AND ((MsysObjects.Type)=1))
ORDER BY MsysObjects.Name;
```

### Expected result:

Name    RecordTotal

table1  5

table2  9

table3  0

### Actual result:

"Syntax error in date in query expression DCount("*",[Name],"[datecreated]<" & #20190101#'.

### 4. Query with weird criteria added to DCount (datecreated > 01/01/9999):

```
SELECT MsysObjects.Name, DCount("*",[Name],"[datecreated]>" & #01/01/9999#) AS RecordTotal
FROM MsysObjects
WHERE (((Left$([Name],1))<>"~") AND ((Left$([Name],4))<>"Msys") AND ((MsysObjects.Type)=1))
ORDER BY MsysObjects.Name;
```

### Expected result:

Name    RecordTotal

table1  0

table2  0

table3  0

### Actual result:

Name    RecordTotal

table1  10

table2  10

table3  10

Comment: What's the DBMS? If this is for Microsoft Access, please remove the [tag:access] tag and change it to [tag:ms-access]. When you add a tag information about pos up, which you should read. The information on the [tag:access] clearly says "DO NOT USE this tag for Microsoft Access"!

Comment: @stickybit Done.

Comment: Why do you have nearly 500 tables in an Access database? This is more a database design issue than SQL one. If tables are same structure with suffixes to distinguish consider migrating all to **one** table and avoid `MSys` tables. Access tables have no row limit.

Comment: @Parfait  - True, and good advice. That will be a task for another day, at which point we'll probably remove the db from access altogether. It's an organizational database, and I've recently come into the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get wrong results, because you concatenate the criteria, what converts your dates to string.
E.g.

```sql
DCount("*",[Name],"[datecreated]<" & #01/01/2019#)
```

gets

```sql
DCount("*",[Name],"[datecreated]<01/01/2019")
```

`/`slash is the divide operator:
1 divided by 1 divided by 2019 ~ 0.0049529

Resuting criteria:

```sql
DCount("*",[Name],"[datecreated]<0.0049529
```

That explains the zero results, because dates are stored as integer values, where 1899-12-30 is represented by the value 0 (try`Debug.Print CLng(#1899-12-30#)`), the day after  1899-12-31 is 1 and the day before 1899-12-29 is -1. All your dates are after that (>1).

The same for

```sql
DCount("*",[Name],"[datecreated]>" & #01/01/9999#)
```

what gets 1 divided by 1 divided by 9999 ~ 0.0001

```sql
DCount("*",[Name],"[datecreated]>0.0001")
```

And as your dates are greater than 1899-12-30, all are count.

Conclusion: If you concat date criteria always suround date with`#`-strings and use US-Format (mm/dd/yyyy) or ISO-Format(yyyy-mm-dd).

```sql
DCount("*",[Name],"[datecreated]<#" & "01/01/2019" & "#")
```

or convert them to numbers:

```sql
DCount("*",[Name],"[datecreated]<" & CLng(#01/01/2019#))
```

If you have datetimes (time <> 00:00:00), convert to Double as time is the fraction as part of the day.

Comment: _relizt's_ own answer shows how to include a date value.

Comment: Thanks, this is incredibly helpful. Although I was able to find a solution that worked, I didn't know why it worked. Your answer explains and gives me information to expand from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This ended up working:

```
SELECT MsysObjects.Name, DCount("*",[Name],"datecreated IS NOT NULL AND datecreated > #01-01-2019#") AS RecordTotal
FROM MsysObjects
WHERE (((Left$([Name],1))<>"~") AND ((Left$([Name],4))<>"Msys") AND ((MsysObjects.Type)=1))
ORDER BY MsysObjects.Name;
```

Comment: This was the solution I found before @computerversteher explained a fuller answer. I'll leave it here for posterity.